# How to Fix This Random URL Redirect On click

Tags: javascript

I try to find a solution with random link code but i cannot find someone that have exactly the same problem with me.

i want to use

```
whatsapp://send?text=&phone=
```

as a link because it much faster  to open whatapps rather than using a normal whatsapp link

```
 https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=
```

My problem is, when i insert:

```
  whatsapp://send?text=&phone=
```

in the code, the button doesnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Button</h2>

 <h3>Click Here</h3>

 <input type="button" value=“new” onclick="randomlink()">

   <script>
     function randomlink() {
       var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
       var link1="whatsapp://send?text=Hi&phone=+201111111"
       var link2="whatsapp://send?text=Hi&phone=+201111222"
       var link3="whatsapp://send?text=Hi&phone=+201111333"
     if (myrandom==0)
        window.open=link1
     else if (myrandom==1)
        window.open=link2
     else if (myrandom==2)
        window.open=link3
     }

      </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Please help me in this. Provide me working JavaScript code.

Comment: `window.open` is a **function** and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` is a function that you have to pass parameters into

Try changing each to this format

```
window.open(link1)
```